# xargs equivalent in perl

Tags: perl, shell, exec, fork, xargs

I liked to make something, what xargs in shellscripting does. Thus:

1. Running external commands by the `exec()` system calls
2. as child processes
3. parallel
4. waiting their execution (ideally with a timeout)

How can it be done in perl?

Comment: Have a look to [Proc::Background](http://search.cpan.org/~bzajac/Proc-Background-1.10/lib/Proc/Background.pm)'s `timeout_system()` sub.

Comment: @FilippoLauria Thank you - although the parallel _waiting_ _their_ _exits_ them is probably a little bit tricky with this extension, because the wait method can be used on a single background process. If you convert this to an answer, I were happy to accept or/and upvote that.

Comment: How about `alarm()` in forked pids?

Comment: @mpapec Yes and I could wait() even in a loop. It works probably and this is what I will do, although it had to be better automatized, my goal is reachable on this way as well.

Comment: xargs doesn't execute the children in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Proc::Background` module.
Particularly interesting is the sub `timeout_system(..)`.

Here's an example coming from the [Proc::Background](http://search.cpan.org/~bzajac/Proc-Background-1.10/lib/Proc/Background.pm) module page:

```
use Proc::Background;
timeout_system($seconds, $command, $arg1);
timeout_system($seconds, "$command $arg1");

my $proc1 = Proc::Background->new($command, $arg1, $arg2);
my $proc2 = Proc::Background->new("$command $arg1 1>&2");
$proc1->alive;
$proc1->die;
$proc1->wait;
my $time1 = $proc1->start_time;
my $time2 = $proc1->end_time;

# Add an option to kill the process with die when the variable is
# DETROYed.
my $opts  = {'die_upon_destroy' => 1};
my $proc3 = Proc::Background->new($opts, $command, $arg1, $arg2);
$proc3    = undef;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @join;
push @join, fasync {
  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };
  alarm 10;
  # exec(..);
  sleep 20;
  print "job1\n";
};
push @join, fasync {

  print "job2\n";
};

# wait for jobs
$_->() for @join;


sub fasync(&) {
  my ($worker) = @_;

  my $pid = fork() // die "can't fork!";
  if ($pid == 0) {
    $worker->();
    exit(0);
  }
  return sub {
    my ($flags) = @_;
    return waitpid($pid, $flags // 0);
  }
}
```